# On Which Fields EnsureIndex() should Use?

Tags: mongodb

I am using golang as backend with mongodb.I want to process a large number of documents and I am using mgo library for Pipe() like below.

```
collection := session.DB("db").C("employee")
        condition = bson.M{
        "city":   "xyz",
        "degree": "phd",
    }

    var localField string = "emp_dept"
        var foreignField string = "dept_name"
        matchStage := bson.M{"$match": condition}
        lookupStage := bson.M{"$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "department",
            "localField":   localField,
            "foreignField": foreignField,
            "as":           "department_info",
        }}
        
        pipeline := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{
            matchStage,
            lookupStage,
            {"$unwind": "$department_info"},
        })
    
        err = pipeline.All(&listed)
```

And My Collections are

**Collection employee-**

```
{
  _id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"qwert",
  "emp_id":111,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
}
{
_id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"asdfg",
  "emp_id":121,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
}... so on
```

**Collection department-**

```
{
_id:ObjectId(),
"dept_id":11,
"dept_name":"XYZ",
"description":"decs",
}...so on
```

So this code basically response in minutes but I want to get results more fast.I am not getting right way to create index.I want to use effective way for indexing so that during insertion and updation index will not slow down the execution time.

I am confused between

```
db.employee.createIndex({"country":1}, {'background' : true})
db.employee.createIndex({"degree":1}, {'background' : true})
```

**OR**

```
db.employee.createIndex({"country":1,"degree":1}, {'background' : true})
```

Which One is more effective?

AND creating index on foreign key field

db.department.createIndex({"dept_name":1}, {'background' : true})

Is this the effective way to create index for lookup or Do I have to create index on local field in lookup as well?

Or instead of indexing limit() the record is better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First variation is indivual index. If you query with country, then country index will be used. If you query with degree then degree index will be used. If you query by both, query planner will use one index either country or degree.

Secound variation is compound index if you query by both in order, then country and degree index ll be used. If you query by country, as country is first part of the inde, then this index will be used. If you query by only degree, this index ll not ve used.

Effectiveness is based on your use case.

Comment: what about the lookup fields indexing?

Comment: It does use index. To understand more, try with aggregate-lookup.